# How to use Otsu Threshold on desired range of a histogram

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I know how to use Otsu threshold and how it works, so no explanation of how to implement it needed. I am interested in c++ implementation in opencv.

I'm looking for a way to use Otsu's method to calculate threshold on the image that have the following histogram:

[image]

The problem here is, that there are a lot of pixels with values from 0 - 25, so this is disturbing the calculation. Is there any way to let say use Otsu's method on only part of a histogram. Let say I want to ignore pixels from 0 to 25 on the histogram above, and calculate threshold only on the range of histogram ( from 50 - 255). The code I'm looking for is something like:

```
range = [from 50 to 255];
// Calculate threshold using Otsu method on the histogram range from 50 to 255.
threshold = cv::threshold(inputImage, outputImage, range, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU);
```

Code that I am using for histogram show is:

```
void show_histogram(std::string const& name, cv::Mat1b const& image){
// Set histogram bins count
int bins = 256;
int histSize[] = { bins };
// Set ranges for histogram bins
float lranges[] = { 0, 256 };
const float* ranges[] = { lranges };
// create matrix for histogram
cv::Mat hist;
int channels[] = { 0 };

// create matrix for histogram visualization
int const hist_height = 256;
cv::Mat3b hist_image = cv::Mat3b::zeros(hist_height, bins);

cv::calcHist(&image, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false);

double max_val = 0;
minMaxLoc(hist, 0, &max_val);

// visualize each bin
for (int b = 0; b < bins; b++) {
    float const binVal = hist.at<float>(b);
    int   const height = cvRound(binVal*hist_height / max_val);
    cv::line
    (hist_image
        , cv::Point(b, hist_height - height), cv::Point(b, hist_height)
        , cv::Scalar::all(255)
    );
}
cv::namedWindow("my Histogram", WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL);
cv::imshow("my Histogram", hist_image); }
```

Comment: AFAICT there's not variant of `threshold` that would let you use a mask. This would be the ideal approach. | Rough idea, you should be able to make this more efficient. 1) mask the unwanted pixels, setting them to 0. 2) findNonZero 3) put only the non-zero values to a new Mat (you need to size this right) 4) run Otsu on this and keep the threshold value it returns. 5) use this value tho do regular threshold on the full image

Comment: Your rought idea seems to work, but any code tips for implementation? I added code that I am displaying histogram with.

Comment: One of the way that also fits yours is to change ranges for histogram bins: `float lranges[] = { 0, 256 };` , change to `float lranges[] = { 25, 256 };`